# How to select radicand

Tags: list-manipulation

Given

```
t1 = {1, Sqrt[2], Sqrt[3], 2, Sqrt[5], Sqrt[6], Sqrt[7], 2 Sqrt[31], 3, Sqrt[10], Sqrt[11], 2 Sqrt[17]};
```

I just want to get all radicands, which would yield

```
{2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 31, 10, 11, 17}
```

I can do it by

```
t2 = t1 /. 1/2 -> e
t3 = DeleteCases[t2, _Integer]
t4 = Replace[#, _*s_^e -> s^e] & /@ t3
t5 = Replace[#, s_^e -> s] & /@ t4
```

Any other elegant way do it?

Comment: `Cases[t1, Sqrt[x_] :> x, Infinity]`

Comment: Wow! Super short

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# & @@@ Cases[t1, _Power, All]
```

> ```
>  {2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 31, 10, 11, 17}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Another way

```
Cases[t1, Sqrt[x_] :> x, Infinity]
(* {2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 31, 10, 11, 17} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming all expressions are either product of a square root or square root on its own:

```
First /@ Cases[t1, Sqrt[_], Infinity]
(* result: {2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 31, 10, 11, 17} *)
```